# Help with Diagram of the Standard Lift of Projective Plane

Tags: projective-geometry, visualization, projective-space

I am posting here because I need help finding (or making) a visual aid for a presentation.

I am giving a short presentation about Projective Geometry next week, and I am building a beamer for it. One such slide talks about the Standard Lift of the Projective Plane, and how it serves as a way to coordinatize the Plane (albeit with infinitely many different coordinate triples for any point in the Projective Plane).

I am trying to find a diagram of the Standard Lift of the plane. I.e. define $\mathbb{RP} ^2$ as the set of lines through the origin in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and then consider the plane $z=1$. Each line (except those sitting in the $xy$-plane) intersects the plane $z=1$ at exactly one point, $(x,y,1)$ and we can use that as a representative vector of the point $[x,y,1] \in \mathbb{RP} ^2$. Furthermore, the lines sitting in the $xy$-plane form the ideal line of $\mathbb{RP} ^2$.

Does anyone know where I could find a diagram of what I just described? Maybe one of Euclidean 3-space with axes labeled, the plane $z=1$, and a few examples? Or have suggestions of software I can use to easily draw this? Preferably I could just use an existing diagram but I know that might be wishful thinking.

Answer (score 0):

If you google images of projective plane, you might find what you want. For example: [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=projective%20plane&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=_jHdVJuVA4v5UK2cg5AP&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&biw=1525&bih=679&dpr=0.9#imgdii=_&imgrc=5M_q7gFDEpEc8M%253A%3BfoBRWriHmMAOnM%3Bhttps%253A%252F%252Fcourses.cs.washington.edu%252Fcourses%252Fcse557%252F97wi%252Fnotes%252Fxforms%252Fdiagram%252Fprojective2.gif%3Bhttps%253A%252F%252Fcourses.cs.washington.edu%252Fcourses%252Fcse557%252F97wi%252Fnotes%252Fxforms%252Fprojective.html%3B676%3B448). Latex and Matlab have some tools for drawing.